# SQL Server - Date style from MM/dd/yyyy to dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got a SQL Server DB where it looks at dates as "MM/dd/yyyy" (i.e American style) and I want it to be the European style ("dd/MM/yyyy") - I remember there is some command that would do that, but can't remember which one.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but it won't give the function to alter the global date format - only for a session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way a date is formatted in client applications like SQL Server Management Studio depends on the user's (login) settings.

Just select the login's language.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Dates and times are stored internally independent of the Culture or language settings. So there is no conversion necessary.

"Styling" your dates is in the responsibility of your programming language and should be done there.

And putting and getting dates into/from the database is possible with these [tricks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191307.aspx):

```
SELECT *
FROM AdventureWorks2008R2.Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE OrderDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '20060719', 101)
```

Comment: But there is the "culture" of the DB which effects the DATE format. The code has already been written and assumes it's 'dd/MM/YYYY' - I can't control that. Now I just need to make sure the DB will use the same format

Comment: This is wrong. Any parameterized SQL statement accepts the date as the date representation of the programming language. Hopefully you don't do something like `INSERT INTO table (thedate) VALUES ('12/24/2011');` Clue: SQL-code-injection.

Comment: @mailq, there's nothing fundamentally wrong with using `INSERT` statements, though you are correct that they are commonly very easy to abuse. +1 the API should be used; or at the least it almost always has a date conversion function to ensure it's formatted properly for the DB. APIs are written for a reason.

Comment: Sadly, this application is using direct INSERT statements - so it DOES use '12/24/2011'... The answer was to use the language for each user (where one was the web app using it)